# Is there a way to write a Jekyll liquid template that automatically prints headers and subheaders of a markdown file?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll site with markdown that looks like this:

```
#Header 1

Some text

##Subheader 1

Some subheader text

#Header 2

etc
```

Is it possible to write a liquid template, so that my sidebar can show a sort of table of contents with all the headers and subheaders?

(fake code):

```
{{%foreach header | print header %}}
 {{%foreach subheader | subheader here %}} 
{{%end%}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is Table of Content or ToC.

With Kramdown, the default Jekyll Markdown parser, you have it out of the box.

```
* Will be replaced with the ToC, excluding the "Contents" header
{:toc}

#Header 1

Some text

##Subheader 1

Some subheader text

#Header 2
```

[See Kramdown documentation for options](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc)